# Asset access error in APK made by using shell script

Tags: android, build-automation, apk, assets

I wrote the shell script to build APK to automate build process. It's like below.

```
    rm -rf obj
    rm -rf gen
    rm -rf bin
    rm -f build.xml
    rm -f local.properties
    rm -f proguard-project.txt

    ndk-build

    android update project --path ./ 

    ant release 

    jarsigner -verbose -keystore path/keystore -storepass password -signedjar bin/myApp-release-signed.apk bin/myApp-release-unsigned.apk alias
```

Currently, I got the APK successfully. But I found sometimes app is crashed when it try to access special asset like texture image. LogCat shows the log like below.

```
    04-10 12:46:25.080: E/szipinf(2255): Error reading asset data
    04-10 12:46:25.080: E/szipinf(2255): Unable to access asset data: -1
```

Eclipse can build APK well. I tried to find the way to fox APK's issue. But I cannot find.

Currently, I'm using android-12 and ndk-r6b. Also I'm working on Machintosh. Is there any special guide to fix such a thing?

Comment: I found there are no error when I tried to use debug sign.

Comment: Using private keystore file makes this problem. But I stil wonder the root cause. Anybody can help?